# twitter bootstrap layout with navbar and vertially aligned carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the following layout done with twitter bootstrap:

navbar at the top
carousel aligned at the middle of the screen
a line of text at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: fluid-rows, vAlign jquery plugin, tried writing some custom css code (I'm horrible at it so no luck), tried modifying a couple of bootstrap layouts from the net - can't get it to work.

Comment: I am only able to go as good [as this](https://scrobly.com/F8QgIruhpmboIcks0XYd) so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall layout is pretty simple so I guess your real issue is the vertical alignment of your carousel for which you could probably try something like:

```
#carousel-outer{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
#carousel {
    height: 300px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -400px;
    background: #000;
}

<div id="carousel-outer">
    <div id="carousel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [This is perfect](https://scrobly.com/GCVwZD9zY9NCQizM4i9a), so many thanks! Is there any way to move the navigation arrows to sit withing the image? If I set the width of carousel-outer to auto it does that but moves the image from the center to the left of the screen...

Comment: Hmm.. no. You have to put your arrows in another div, say #arrows and then position this div with CSS. If you post your actual markup would be easier to help.